# Bechor that also the only son

Tags: bechor-firstborn

Does a bechor needs to have younger siblings? Is he still be a bechor if he happen to be the only son in the family?

Comment: There are different kinds of Bechor. Which do you refer to? That he inherits a double portion? Even without the double portion he'll inherit everything. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: linguistically, "oldest" can only exist in comparison with two or more other siblings but a first born is first as soon as he is first. He might eventually be last, but for the moment, he is first.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, he will inherit everything so the halacha of "double" portion does not apply. However, the halacha of pidyon haben (redeeming the first born) does apply as does the custom of fasting on erev Pesach.

The halacha as given in the Torah says that pidyon haben is required 30 days after the birth of the bechor. In most cases, a woman will give birth to a single child rather than a multiple birth (such as twins or triplets). Obviously, in most cases, at that time he has no siblings. Thus we see that the halacha applies whether or not the bechor is an only child.

The fast of the first born applies whether or not a bechor is an only child as we see at [Why do the first born fast on erev Pesach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56358/why-do-the-first-born-fast-on-erev-pesach) or [this citation of the Tur](http://www.torahmusings.com/2010/03/erev-pesach-fast-of-firstborn/)

> It is customary[1] for **all** firstborn males to fast on Erev Pesach in
>   order to recall the tenth and final plague which God inflicted upon
>   Egypt – the death of the firstborn.
>
> [1] Tur 429, 470, Mishna Berura 470:7

Note that while the first born is a child, the father will fast for him (as does one of my sons for his bechor).